# Regedit deleted and now want to restore it using cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, cmd.exe

I have  made a copy of regedit on by desktop (by exporting it), after that I deleted some of registries entries(hkey_local_machine) due to which now my system does not restart. Can you tell me how to restore the regedit copy on my desktop using command promt as I am able to open cmd under advance option.

My windows is 10
I have tried to open safe mode but didn't work.
Tried to reset pc and that also didn't work.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Did you delete Regedit itself, or stuff in the registry?

Comment: stuff in registry

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify that.

Comment: plz help me i have some useful stuff that i don't wnat to lose

Comment: can you not just double click on the the `.reg` backup to re-import the data?

Comment: no as my window is not booting.

Comment: Your regedit backup is stored on the machine you were editing regedit on...?

Comment: yes it is stored in same machine

Comment: Since you can load a command prompt, did you try to run `regedit` from it?

Answer (score 1):

Regedit.exe is just the editor application, with which you can edit the registry hive contents. Restoring this executable won't bring back your deleted registry keys and values.

If the system is unbootable, boot your computer using the installation media (or) recovery drive, get into the Repair / Recovery Options page and do a System Restore rollback from there. Refer the [instructions here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/locked-user-account-lost-admin-privileges-rescue/).

**Note**: You may need to first change the boot order in the BIOS setup page and set it to boot from USB or DVD (depending upon which installation media you're going to use).